# How to get output to STDOUT in Rsync while only logging changes to “--log-file” the way Rsync 2.6.9 did with Rsync 3.x

Tags: macos, rsync, logging

As a longtime macOS user I have used the built-in/bundled rsync binary that has been stuck at version 2.6.9 for various licensing reasons.

I recently decided to start using modern rsync via Homebrew. Everything is working fine, but one thing i cannot figure out is how to have verbose output during the sync, but have the saved log only show the updated/changed files.

This was default behavior with rsync 2.6.9 and I cannot figure how to do the same thing in rsync 3.x. here is an example:

```
rsync -avv --progress --stats --log-file=rsync.log /source/ /dest/
```

In rsync 2.6.9, due the double `vv`, the STDOUT during the sync is verbose, and shows everything, but the `rsync.log` file only shows which files were updated/changed/deleted. But I cannot figure out how to achieve the same thing in rsync 3.2.3.

I have looked extensively at the [man pages](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.1) but it’s not clear to me how to change this. I see a lot of posts about using the `--itemize-changes` switch, but this seems to affect both the STDOUT and the log.

I also see the `--log-file-format` switch, but that seems to only affect the format of each line of the log, not what is actually spit out.

So what I am essentially trying to do is see verbose STDOUT but then suppress of all of the `uptodate` messages in the log. Can this be done in modern 3.x rsync?